# Inno Setup executes batch file but it doesn't let it create its .txt file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, installation, inno-setup, pascal

My installer executes two bat files I have created one after another, the batch files run but they do not create the two `.txt` files they are supposed to create. When I execute them manually the do their job perfectly but from Inno Setup they just flash for a moment in the screen and do not create the txt files they are supposed to create.

This is my code, please help. I have scoured the internet for a solution for but I haven't found any.

```pascal
[Code]
function InitializeSetup(): boolean;
var
  ResultCode: integer;
begin
  // this bat file creates 2 txt files with the hardware id, one is permanent one is temporary
  Exec(ExpandConstant('{src}\gethardwareid_win.bat'), '', '', SW_SHOW,
     ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) ;

  // this one verify if the 2 files are the same, if they are it creates an answer.txt 
  Exec(ExpandConstant('{src}\verify.bat'), '', '', SW_SHOW,
     ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) ;

  //if the answer.txt file exists it means the two collected hardware id are the same and it continues installatin, if not it aborts it
  if FileExists(ExpandConstant('{src}\answer.txt')) then
  begin
    // handle success if necessary; ResultCode contains the exit code
    MsgBox('correct', mbCriticalError, MB_OK);
    Result:=True
  end
    else
  begin
    // handle failure if necessary; ResultCode contains the error code
    MsgBox('this is not the licensed computer', mbCriticalError, MB_OK);
    Result:=False
  end;

  // Proceed Setup
end;
```

The batch files 1)  gethardwareid_win.bat

```
@echo off
@rem 
@rem HelpSystems hardware ID discovery for Windows
@rem 

@rem setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set outfile=out.txt
set verify= verify.txt
set internfile=1
set "indent=   "

if NOT "x%1" == "x" (
  set outfile=%1
  set internfile=0
)
set removedStr=%outfile:~1,-1%

set computername= 
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('hostname') do @set computername=%%a

@rem delete the old output file if existed
if exist %outfile% del %outfile%
echo Hardware ID(s) for computer:
echo Hardware ID(s) for computer: >> %outfile%

@rem run "getmac" command to get all the Mac addresses
SET count=0
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%a in ('"getmac /NH"') do (

    if NOT "x%%a"=="x" (
        if NOT "%%a"=="N/A " (
        call :formatHardwareId %%a 
        set /a count+=1
        )
    )    
)

@rem copy to clipboard
@rem echo Found IDs: %count%
if count gtr 0 (
   clip < %outfile%
) else (
   echo No hardware ID found.
)
echo.


@rem remove out file if not specified externally

@rem ENDLOCAL

@rem ---------------------------------------------------------



if NOT "x%1" == "x" (
  set verify=%1
  set internfile=0
)
set removedStr=%verify:~1,-1%

set computername= 
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('hostname') do @set computername=%%a

@rem delete the old output file if existed
if exist %verify% (goto:eof)
else( echo Hardware ID(s) for computer:
echo Hardware ID(s) for computer: >> %verify%

@rem run "getmac" command to get all the Mac addresses
SET count=0
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%a in ('"getmac /NH"') do (

    if NOT "x%%a"=="x" (
        if NOT "%%a"=="N/A " (
        call :formatHardwareId1 %%a 
        set /a count+=1
        )
    )    
)

@rem copy to clipboard
@rem echo Found IDs: %count%
if count gtr 0 (
   clip < %verify%
) else (
   echo No hardware ID found.
)
echo.


@rem remove out file if not specified externally

@rem ENDLOCAL
goto:eof)
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------


@rem ---------------------------------------------------------
@rem function to format the Hardware ID
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------
:formatHardwareId

  SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION  
  set  localmac=%1
  @rem set  localmac=%localmac:~1,-1%
  set  localmac=%localmac:-=:%

  if NOT "x%1"=="x" ( 
      @rem echo local: %localmac%
      if NOT "%localmac%"=="%removedStr%" (
    if NOT "%localmac%"=="N/A" (
          echo %indent% W-%localmac%
          echo %indent% W-%localmac% >> %outfile%
    )
      )
   )
   ENDLOCAL
exit /b
@rem 

:formatHardwareId1

  SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION  
  set  localmac=%1
  @rem set  localmac=%localmac:~1,-1%
  set  localmac=%localmac:-=:%

  if NOT "x%1"=="x" ( 
      @rem echo local: %localmac%
      if NOT "%localmac%"=="%removedStr%" (
    if NOT "%localmac%"=="N/A" (
          echo %indent% W-%localmac%
          echo %indent% W-%localmac% >> %verify%
    )
      )
   )
   ENDLOCAL
exit /b
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------
```

The second batch file 2)  verify.bat

```
@echo off
set ans=answer.txt
if exist %ans% del %ans% 

for /f "Delims=" %%a in (out.txt) do (

set TEXT=%%a

)

for /f "Delims=" %%a in (verify.txt) do (

set TEXT1=%%a

)

if %text1%==%TEXT% echo 1 > answer.txt
```

Comment: Check for permissions for a destination folder where txt files being created.

Comment: No that is not the case i double checked on that, the folder is in a cd.

Comment: @Edi, but CD (Compact Disc) is a read-only media. Can you post the contents of your batch files in the question?

Comment: @wOxxOm i have tried it in other folders of my computer also and changed permissions and the results are the same, i have checked those posibilities long ago.

Comment: There's a common "trick": create the files in `TEMP` folder: `"%TEMP%\out.txt"`, `"%TEMP%\verify.txt"`, `"%TEMP%\answer.txt"`.

Comment: Removing `@echo off` can often help you out...

Comment: NO NONE OF THIS HAS WORKED

Comment: Is Inno setup running in the same context as the user? It could be creating the text file in %windir%\system or %windir%\temp or something. Try adding `cd` then `pause` to your batch script to verify the current working directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using relative paths in the batch file and you do not specify a startup directory of the batch file. This is pretty unreliable approach.

The files are created (if created at all) probably in some temporary folder.

---

To debug the batch files, remove `@echo off` and add `pause` at the end of the batch file. This allows you to inspect the batch file output.